# jQuery UI adding classes and attributes to my html code which is not desired

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I added a reference to jQuery UI library and it is modifying the html on the page.  Simply by adding a reference to the jQuery-ui.min.js file, my HTML is being modified.

i.e. without the reference I see this:

`<div id="myMenu">`

after the js reference to the jQuery UI library I see the following:

`<div id="myMenu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem">`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there is no jquery code triggering this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. So I created a plugin called menu and applied it to my ordered list via something like $('mymenu').menu({....});
After I added a reference to jquery-ui it must also have a plugin 'menu' and so it was adding all sorts of css classes and attributes to my list html elements.

I need to rename my custom plugin to be more specific to me (i.e. appmenu).

Comment: Namespacing will probably be helpful as you go forwards.